# FOPEN_MAX and _SC_OPEN_MAX

Tags: c

On my system (Ubunut 13.10), value for `FOPEN_MAX` is 16, value for `_POSIX_OPEN_MAX` is 20, and value for `_SC_OPEN_MAX` (I got it through `sysconf()`) is 4096. I know that `_POSIX_OPEN_MAX` is the minimum value for `OPEN_MAX` defined by *POSIX.1* standard. So here, the real value is `_SC_OPEN_MAX`. Also, value for `FOPEN_MAX` is defined by *ISO C*. Both of them call themselves to designate the same thing: maximum open files supported by a process.

*Question*: But why of the discrepancy between `FOPEN_MAX` and `_SC_OPEN_MAX`, and what should be the one that I rely on when I'm writing my *C* application?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you use `getconf` command on `_POSIX_OPEN_MAX`, do you get the same value ?

Comment: @Thomas _POSIX_OPEN_MAX isn't a variable at all - it's set in stone in the standard. The _POSIX macros have the same value everywhere, always (unless revised by newer standards, but...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The discrepancy is because one is dynamic, one is static. If you write software for Ubuntu systems, the numbers are telling you'll always be able to rely on 20 open files (POSIX here is guaranteeing more than plain C's 16 limit). So you could theoretically compile some stuff conditionally to do crazy stuff to work around a low limit, to make sure the software will work on all systems with the same headers.

The runtime limit, _SC_OPEN_MAX, is the actual fd limit. It might be lower on some systems, but not below 20 (for any POSIX OS).

Finally, OPEN_MAX is the OS-specific lower limit for _SC_OPEN_MAX (that is, _POSIX_OPEN_MAX is telling you that on any POSIX system, OPEN_MAX has to be at least 20). Linux will define OPEN_MAX to be something higher, so you can rely on having more fds available, and will prevent _SC_OPEN_MAX going below the actual OPEN_MAX.

Answer (score 6):

You got to remember that on POSIX systems a file descriptor doesn't actual have to be a *file*. It may also be a socket, a pipe or something else that can be used by e.g. `read` or `write`. So `_SC_OPEN_MAX` will return the max number of "open" *descriptors* you can have, not the max number of files.

Also, `FOPEN_MAX` is, as you note, specific to the C language and the C library, and is related to the `fopen` library call and not the lower `open` system call.