# Is FILE * reassignment without fclose() okay?

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, fclose, file-pointer

Suppose I have the following code :

```c
FILE *x = fopen("story.txt",r);
if(x!=NULL)
{
    x = fopen("story.txt",wb); /* <- Does this waste/leak memory ?? */
    /* ... do something .... */
    /* if(fclose(x)==EOF)...else... */
}
else
{
    printf("story.txt does not exist\n");
}
```

Here, I'm reassigning the pointer to where a buffer for `story.txt`was created in memory , without `fclose(x)` , assuming that since it is a pointer, the memory area will simply be *overwritten* to with the ' *new* ' buffer. Is this assumption accurate ? Am I leaking or wasting memory , or is the approach okay ?

Comment: In stdio.h there is a definition for `FOPEN_MAX`, which is the maximum number of files that you can have open (using `fopen`) at any one time. That includes the 3 standard streams: stdin, stdout, and stderr. The C standard says, *"The value of FOPEN_MAX shall be at least eight"*. So in theory, if the program reassigns the pointer 5 times without closing the file, the `fopen` function may no longer work. It could simply return NULL every time.

Comment: You've missed that you aren't *passing* `FILE * x` but are instead **storing** the address returned by `fopen("story.txt","wb")` *into* the pointer-variable `x`. So `x` is overwritten, **not** `*x`.

Comment: @user3386109 out of curiosity , on POSIX & windows machines, what is the value of `FOPEN_MAX` ?

Comment: The value of `FOPEN_MAX` is in one of the `.h` files (e.g. `stdio.h` or some other one it does a `#include` on). But, an easy way is to do: `printf("FOPEN_MAX=%d\n",FOPEN_MAX);` as the first line of `main`. But, it's 16 under linux, so I'm not sure that is the limit for number of open streams (e.g. 1024 would be a more reasonable number)

Comment: [Here's a question that sort of answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20000077/fopen-max-and-sc-open-max). TLDR: it is what it is. So if you really need to use every available FILE, the code should be looking at `FOPEN_MAX` and `_POSIX_OPEN_MAX` to see how many are available. If you want to know what the limits are on your machine, just `printf` the macros, as @ CraigEstey suggested.

Comment: If you do (e.g.) `fopen("/dev/null","r")` in a loop until it returns `NULL` and _count_ the number of loop iterations, you'll get `1021` [which is 1024 minus the already open streams `stdin/stdout/stderr`]

Comment: another problem here is attempting to open for writing a file that's already open for reading

Comment: Take a look at [`freopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3p.html) . This is one of its use cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just leaked a file handle. If you do it enough, you'll run out of open file handles to allocate, and all attempts to open a file will fail. Don't do that. `fclose` your `FILE*`s.

There is no reason to think the "memory area" would be overwritten here; you're overwriting the *pointer*, not what it points to, and what it points to is the file related structures (`stdio` buffers, descriptor of the underlying kernel file handle, etc.). It no more overwrites the memory being pointed to than assigning a second `malloc` to the same pointer overwrites what the first `malloc` pointed to; you're leaking the first resource acquisition in both cases by losing the original pointer in favor of the new one.

Comment: ShadowRanger okay, so this is **not** okay, but perhaps you could tell me in more *detail* what you mean by ' *leaked a file handle* ' and how I did that ? I'm new, so I don't understand it :)

Comment: @user13863346, There's a limit on how many open file handles a process can have. If you open fds without closing you could run out.

Comment: @ikegami I see 0_0

Comment: @user13863346: To be clear, if you did this exactly once in a program, and never again, you probably wouldn't suffer for it. Leak detectors might catch it, but the program would run, and even your leaked handle would get closed when the process finally exits and the OS reclaims all process resources. But it's a *really* bad habit to get into; the moment you put something like this in a loop, you risk file handle exhaustion. Plus, any maintainer who sees an obvious mistake like this will assume the original author was a sloppy coder, and have to spend more time verifying the code isn't broken.

Comment: Ah, so the 'memory area' won't be overwritten , hmm ... I didn't think that I was overwriting the pointer instead of what it pointed to 0_0 ... As for my actual program, I was proof-reading it and found 2 spots where I did this, and if its wrong its wrong, I'll correct it , not a big change.

Answer (score 1):

The major problem is that many operating systems have a **limit** on a number of open files each process can have, which is because there is literally an array of all files in the kernel data structures for each process which must have enough space for all files in the process.

If you overwrite the pointer, there is (usually = never if you did not do it by yourself) no garbage collection in C, so the system would not know that the `FILE` structure pointed to by the pointer should be free - and this will result in a memory leak. But the worse leak is the leak of limited operating system resources.

The situation will naturally fix itself after you exit your program - all unclosed files will be closed and flushed then. But is it really that hard to put the `fclose` there:

```
FILE *x = fopen("story.txt", r);
if (x != NULL)
{
    fclose(x);
    x = fopen("story.txt", wb); // <- this certainly does not leak any more
```

Comment: Antti , thanks for you answer. No it isn't hard at all :D , and I've done it, I was just wondering what the consequences would be :)